# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode after postback asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url-encoding

I have this in the url:

```
http://localhost:5466/Supplier.aspx?id=Orchidée organisation
```

After a postback on the page the url changes to:

```
http://localhost:5466/Supplier.aspx?id=Orchid%C3%A9e%20organisation
```

How can i maintain the first url after postback

Comment: You don't.  The second URL is the *actual* version of the first one.

Comment: The browser HTML encodes the URL to make it safe.  You simply have to use HTML Decode in your code behind if you need to use that Query String parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i maintain the first url after post back

You don't.  The first URL is technically invalid because it the value isn't URL-encoded.  Most browsers will silently correct this for you.  But the *actual* URL is:

```
http://localhost:5466/Supplier.aspx?id=Orchid%C3%A9e%20organisation
```

Because the [URL-encoded](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) version of:

```
Orchidée organisation
```

is:

```
Orchid%C3%A9e%20organisation
```

(Note: This has nothing to do with HTML-encoding, as your question title suggests.)

---

If you're receiving URL-encoded values somewhere in your server-side code, [`HttpServerUtility` has a `UrlDecode()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx) which can decode them for you.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, but you didnt metion how i can fix that

Comment: @Jmocke: Fix *what* exactly?  You didn't mention what specifically you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: sorry, on post back when the name changes to ~Orchid%C3%A9e%20organisation~ i cant find anymore the details of the supplier since the name is not the same. i want to keep that name exact even after the postback

Comment: @Jmocke: At the end of this answer I mentioned how you can decode an encoded value.  Is that not working in some way?  You have to be specific, I don't know what you've tried.

Comment: @Jmocke: "Remains" *where*?  If that's the URL that's in the user's browser then that would be because that's the URL the user requested.  Decoding the URL in the address bar would likely involve a bit of a JavaScript hack, if it would even work.  Or, I suppose, writing your own web browser.  But that is a standard and correct URL.  What is the actual problem here?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?